# Elegant way to map some properties in one List based on Id from another List in C#

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq

I have a `User` List and `Branch` List. One `Branch` can have multiple `User`. I need to assign few properties in `User` from `Branch` based on `BranchId`. Here are my classes.

**User**:

```cs
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public Guid BranchId { get; set; }
    public string BranchName { get; set; }
}
```

**Branch:**

```cs
public class Branch
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string BranchName { get; set; }
}
```

Here is what I have tried,

```cs
foreach (var user in vm)
{
   var branch = branches.Single(b => b.Id.Equals(user.BranchId));
   user.BranchName = branch.BranchName;   
}
```

Right now this works, but I feel this as not a good solution as to iterate users and get branch everytime for that user and assign that. May be multiple users in the list can have same `BranchId` in that case it happens like I'm reading the same branch again and again. Any better solutions using LINQ or this can be improved in any ways? please assist.

Comment: One small improvement would be to use `.First()` instead of `.Single()`, as the latter always iterates the entire list...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you could create a dictionary mapping from branch ID to brand name:

```
var branchIdToBrandName = branches.ToDictionary(b => b.Id, b => b.BrandName);
foreach (var user in users)
{
    user.BrandName = branchIdToBranchName[user.BranchId];
}
```

That's assuming there's exactly one branch per branch ID, and that every user's branch ID is covered. If you need to do the same for other properties, you'd probably want to just map branch ID to branch, rather than straight to brand name, e.g.:

```
var branchIdToBranch = branches.ToDictionary(branch => branch.Id);
foreach (var user in users)
{
    user.BrandName = branchIdToBranch[user.BranchId].BrandName;
}
```